# Moving Multiple Divs With Same Class Inside Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, My website is hosted on enjin.com and when you give users a tag with an image it appears on the forums under their name, however it's a vertical list with the tag names. I want to organize it so all of the tag images appear on one line and all of the tag names appear on a horizontal list below it.

They use div tags somewhat like this

```
<div class="tag">
    <div class="tag-image"></div> <!-- If the tag lacks an image this is excluded -->
    <div class="tag-text">Tag Name</div> <!-- If you want the name to be hidden this is excluded -->
</div>
```

They then pretty much repeat this for every tag. Somewhat the same thing is used for forum posts too.

So, I want to move all the tag-image divs together on a single line and all of the tag-text divs down and give each it's own line. I only want to move them within their parent element (to avoid images/tags from one forum user from going to another).

I know how to append things with jquery and have googled how to move elements around, but I'm afraid that they're all going to end up together under another user's avatar.

EDIT:
Screenshot for more detail:
[image]

EDIT:
I attempted this:

```
$('.tag-image').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.cell').append($(this));
});
```

Nothing happened. I suspect that this script should be placed in the head tag to work, if it's what I need. I can't do that with my platform, but I'm working on a workaround as I've come across this issue before.

EDIT:
Attempted this:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', moveimgs, false);
    function moveimgs(){
        $('.tag-image').each(function(){
            $(this).parent().find('.cell').append($(this));
        });
}
```

Same result.

Comment: So each div with the class tag can have multiple child divs with the class tag-image, but only one child div with the class tag-text, and the tag-image divs should be aligned horizontally and always above the tag-text div?

Comment: provide structure you want, as well as more specifics about your html comments. No idea what hidden criteria is for `tag-txt` class

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you're trying to do.  If you post more HTML showing before and after and showing multiple images that should be grouped and multiple images that should not be grouped, you're probably much more likely to get an answer that actually does what you want.  Also, make sure you show the parent structure as it looks like you've only shown one item, not multiple items and not multiple parents.

Comment: no, each div with the "tag" class can only have one tag-image and one tag-text. But other than that, you've got it.

Comment: `you've got it` is not doing your part to make the question as concise as possible...with all the detail that anyone needs to comprehend start to finish. TSo often these vauge questions end up with...`.oh yeah...forgot to tell you..` after people put effort into them

Comment: I'm grabbing a screen shot at the moment

Comment: You say you know how to append....you should be trying this first and providing your attempts..to learn from. Which is hole point here....give a guy a fish, or teach him to fish??

Comment: Added a screen shot. I know how to append, but I'm nowhere near competent. I'm not even sure appending is the right way to go, as that would create duplicates of stuff, and for every forum user. If I know how to put a fishing line on a pole but not how to tie weights and hooks, then I won't catch a fish.

Comment: I mean, i don't know If I should do the complete thing like (.parentclass).append(parentclass.tag.tagimg);
Would that do it individually for all tags and only move them within their parent?

Comment: added an attempt. Nothing happened, but I'm working on it.

Comment: Looks like the problem is that the divs are not floated to the left, so...they will take up the whole row and images/texts cant be side by side.
The structure of the tagslooks fine to me.

Comment: Added an attempt to run the js after the page loads, same result.

Comment: You don't think that with the code I added it would at least group the images together instead of nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you are trying to do, but if it something like this, then you should use tables instead.

```
<table class="tag">
    <tr>
        <td><div class="tag-image">
            <img src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/danomyte/danomyte0811/danomyte081100001/3807403-superhero-getting-ready-for-action.jpg" width="30px"/>
        </div></td>
        <td><div class="tag-text">Tag Name</div></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><div class="tag-image">
            <img src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/danomyte/danomyte0811/danomyte081100001/3807403-superhero-getting-ready-for-action.jpg" width="30px"/>
        </div></td>
        <td><div class="tag-text">Tag Name</div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><div class="tag-image">
            <img src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/danomyte/danomyte0811/danomyte081100001/3807403-superhero-getting-ready-for-action.jpg" width="30px"/>
        </div></td>
        <td><div class="tag-text">Tag Name</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/6kTUb/)

Comment: I can't use tables, sorry. I have the luxury of being able to use js but I can't switch to tables unless I so even more work with js to turn it into a table. I can't change how the forums work or generate all of this. The host has their cms all locked down.